# JSON java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, android-volley

> Hello Everyone. I am parsing a JSON response and getting this Error. This is how I am getting JSON Response :

```
    {
    "id": 12,
    "banner_name": "testproject1.indigierp.com/images/banners/promo1.jpg"
}{
    "id": 14,
    "banner_name": "testproject1.indigierp.com/images/banners/promo3.jpg"
}{
    "id": 15,
    "banner_name": "testproject1.indigierp.com/images/banners/promo4.jpg"
}
```

> This is what I have tried on Android :

```
   final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

   String BANNER_URL = "http://testproject1.indigierp.com/api/banner_details";

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, BANNER_URL, null, response -> {

        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("banner_name");
                Log.e("Image", String.valueOf(jsonObject));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           }
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

> Error : `type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

> How can I fix it. Please guide appropriately . Thanks

Comment: _banner_name_ is your string not your _JSONObject_. You need to change _String banner_name = response.getJSONObject("banner_name");_ Also if _response_ is your json array then you have to retrive _JSONObject_ from it by iteration and then retrieve _banner_name_  from that json object.

Comment: Required type:
String
Provided:
JSONObject

Comment: Your response JSON is not a valid JSON. If it's an array then it is missing commas between the JSON objects.

Comment: I have edited my comment. Check it

Answer (score 1):

Your usage is wrong. Try to use it like below. You are trying to pass a string to an Object.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String banner_name = jsonObject.getString("banner_name"))
```